# dispose the existing and open new form in c#

Tags: c#

I have two forms in my program. The first is the login form and the other is the home form.
When i click the 'Enter' button on the login form, it should close or dispose the login form and then open the new home form. I have not been able to do this. Please help me out.

Comment: what you have tried? show us the current code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. The owner of the new form is the 'login form'. Once that closes, so will any other child forms.

I would create the form you are working on first, say the 'home form', hide it, then open the 'login form' using the 'home form' as its parent.

Simply doing this in the constructor of the 'home form' would work. Once the login is complete, close it and show the 'home form'.

eg:

```
public HomeForm()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.hide();

    var login = new LoginForm();
    login.ShowDialog();

    this.Show();
}
```